# ECS - Capacity provider is not scaling out when needed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

we have an ECS cluster in place with Capacity provider associated with an ASG.
We configured memory reservation for all the tasks in the cluster, and all the cluster have the binpack memory placement strategy.

It happens often that ECS cannot place one or more task because the closest matching instance doesn't have enough memory.

I expect that in this case Capacy Provider will scale out adding one or more container instances, but this doesn't happen.

If we adjust the desired count by adding one or more instance the taks, of course, are successfully placed.

Any idea? What else could we check?

Thanks a lot in advance

What we tried:

Adjusting Capacity Provider settings - ASG settings - Manually adding ECS container instances.